# Silverlight WPF VisualStateManager vs MultiDataTrigger

Tags: wpf, silverlight, visualstatemanager

In Silverlight is it always best to use the VisualStateManager when changing the template of of a control like a button?

Or is there support for triggers like Data Triggers in Silverlight?

Im just trying to keep things consistent between WPF and Silverlight applications at work.

Or should I just use VisualStateManager for both WPF and Silverlight applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WPF does now support the `VisualStateManager` whereas Siverlight doesn't have Triggers in the same way WPF does.

So if you want to keep as much as possible consistent then use the `VisualStateManager`.

Comment: Even if you're using just WPF, VSM is the way to go.  It's much easier/cleaner.  That's why they added it to the .NET 4 runtime.